# How can I get the next n number of elements using a Ruby enumerator?

Tags: ruby, enumerator

I am trying to get the next `n` number of elements using a Ruby enumerator, with this:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
enum = a.each
enum.next(2) # expecting [1, 2]
enum.next(2) # expecting [3, 4]
```

But `#next` does not support that.

What is the correct Ruby way to do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `take` method

```
enum.take(2)
```

If you need slices of two elements, you could do:

```
e = enum.each_slice(2)
p e.next
#=> [1, 2]
p e.next
#=> [3, 4]
```

Comment: But this one always return the first 2. Am I wrong?

Comment: @p.matsinopoulos  What is the exact requirement?  Do you wish to retrieve every 2 elements or retrieve arbitrary number of elements from the point you last left the enum at?

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
enum = a.dup
enum.shift(2) # => [1, 2]
enum.shift(2) # => [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the next N number of elements from an enumerator, while also forwarding the enumerator's internal pointer:

```rb
Array.new(n) { enum.next }
```

Note that if you exceed the enumerator's max bound when doing this, a `StopIteration` exception will be raised.

But it won't raise if you're using a cyclic enumerator. Example:

```rb
enum = (1..3).cycle

Array.new(6) { enum.next }
# => [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]
```